# Modelica comments

Tags: syntax, comments, whitespace, grammar, modelica

Does the Modelica specification forbid the type of comments as given in the following example code? 
The tool I am using moves the comment behind the next semicolon.

```
within ;
model HeatingResistor_Comment "Heating resistor"
  extends Modelica.Icons.Example;

  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.HeatingResistor heatingResistor(
    R_ref=100,
    alpha=1e-3,   // taken from Meyer 2016 paper
    T_ref=293.15, // this is 20C
    i(start=0));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground G;
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.SineVoltage SineVoltage1(
    V=220,
    freqHz=1);
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.ThermalConductor thermalConductor(G=50);
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Celsius.FixedTemperature fixedTemperature(T=20);

equation
  connect(SineVoltage1.n, G.p);
  connect(heatingResistor.heatPort, thermalConductor.port_a);
  connect(SineVoltage1.p, heatingResistor.p);
  connect(G.p, heatingResistor.n);
  connect(thermalConductor.port_b, fixedTemperature.port);

end HeatingResistor_Comment;
```

A copy of this example is also here (with syntax highlight):
https://gist.github.com/thorade/c1a0447f2f5c05aefb9e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using OpenModelica then the comments will be moved around unfortunately.
We are planning to fix that but it will take some time.

Comment: The corresponding ticket is this one, I guess: https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/2905

Comment: You don't say it explicitly, but I read your answer as: The Modelica Specification allows these comments and moving them is a bug. So I'll just mark your answer as the solution to my question.

Comment: Yes. The comments are allowed by the Modelica Specification and is a bug that the OpenModelica moves them around. We unparse the AST after parsing that's why the comments (and any other formatting actually) move around.